# Why does this d3 gist work in Chrome but not in Safari - sliders

Tags: d3.js, svg, uicomponents

Here is a link to a gist:

http://bl.ocks.org/rleddy/f06005e9b6b132ece4ac4d4d0efbc375

The sliders, especially seem to work fine in Chrome (oddities still need some work.) But, they don't work at all in Safari.

You get to the sliders if you click on one of the little clocks. Is there a difference in event names?